# How does variable scoping work when splitting a workflow into smaller chunks?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I have a very long workflow for building and testing our application.  So long, in fact, that when we try to load the main workflow script, we get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid method Code length 67768 in class file WorkflowScript
```

I am not proud of this. I'm tying to split the workflow into smaller scripts that we load from the main workflow script, but are running into an issue with variable scoping.  For example:

```
def a = 'foo' //some variable referenced in multiple workflow stages

node {
  echo a
}
//... and then a whole bunch of other stages
```

might become

```
def a = 'foo' //some variable referenced in multiple workflow stages
node {
  git: ...
  load 'flowPartA.groovy'
}()
```

where flowPartA.groovy looks like:

```
{ ->
  node {
    echo a
  }
}
```

Based on my understanding of the documentation, where flowPartA.groovy is interpreted as a closure, I expect the variable 'a' would remain in scope, but instead, I get an exception to the contrary.

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Am I missing something about the way workflow interprets the flow scripts?  Is there a good way to take a huge workflow that uses many, many parameters and split it into smaller chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a function in the external groovy and call it passing all required parameters:

```
def a = 'foo'
node('slave') {
    git '…'
    def flow = load 'flowPartA.groovy'
    flow.echoFromA(a)
}
```

And `flowPartA.groovy` contains:

```
def echoFromA(String a) {
    echo a
}
return this
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#triggering-manual-loading) for more information.